# Can we just share screen using tightvnc server

Tags: vnc

I have installed tightvncserver on my ubuntu system. I know that using a vnc viewer I can control this machine from a remote machine. But I don't want to control this machine remotely. I just want to view what is going on here on the viewer window on a remote machine. e.g. If I open firefox on my machine (in which I've installed tightvncserver), someone else on a remote machine having vnc viewer installed should just be able to see firefox opening in his vnc viewer window. Similarly when I close firefox and open some other application, the same should be visible on the viewer window. Is it possible through VNC?

Answer (score 0):

You can run tightvncserver with the -viewonly Argument.

tightvncserver is a wrapper for xVNC and Takes xVNC Arguments. the viewonly Argument is probably what you're looking for.